# I changed my secondary drive to EFI after a Gentoo install. Can I get my files back?

Tags: linux, windows-10, partitioning, partition-recovery, gentoo

I'll try to explain the situation, because my setup was really strange and I never bothered to fix it.

Basically I had a main 256 GB Crucial SSD with the Windows 10 OS and all of my main work on it. My secondary Seagate 1 TB SSD contained a windows 7 OS, but I wasn't really able to boot to it since the EFI partition was either missing or corrupted. And as such, I just used it as a massive storage device. I had tried to install Gentoo twice in the past on this drive, so it was split into multiple partitions for SWAP and such, with the largest one still containing all of my stuff. Picture below to show how it's split up as well as what it looks like as of this post:

[Disk 0 is my SSD//Disk 1 is my Seagate HDD//Disk 2 is my ext HDD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETolN.png)

Now fast forward to two weeks ago, when I finally installed Gentoo to a USB drive I was pretty excited! However, I was too lazy to install Wine at the moment and I needed to edit videos in Adobe Premiere, so I attempted to go back to Windows 10. For whatever reason though, it wasn't booting no matter what I did with the load order or settings within the BIOS. I was forced to make a backup with another USB I had, and then booted into the recovery screen.

The startup repair didn't work so for whatever reason, and I really don't think I was thinking clearly, I changed the filesystem of the largest partition (which contained all my music and movies) to EFI using the manager in the Windows recovery disk. I then realized I screwed up, and just attempted to wipe my SSD so I could reinstall Windows 10 and boot. It didn't work though. It only could be accomplished with with parted in the Gentoo LiveDisk before I was able to install Windows to it.

I then log into Windows and what do you know? My HDD is totally missing from the list! However, it does show up in the Disk Manager as I showed you earlier. No recovery software can recognize the filesystem on it, obviously, since it's EFI.

Basically guys, I don't know what to do. Can anyone help me?

[My Specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ft1IW.png)

Comment: **EFI isn't a file system so you can't switch to it from MBR.**  Please clarify your question as it's currently not clear what exactly you did.  I believe you meant you converted your MBR HDD to GPT.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on what you exactly did. If you only changed *the type* of the partition, and all the data is still in that 838.19 GB partition, yes, you could recover it, it's just that Windows is hiding it (actually, you could probably right click on it and assign a drive letter).

If that reformatted that partition, removing everything that was there, you could still recover some data (e.g. using testdisk), but it will be much harder and incomplete.

And then, "just attempted to wipe my SSD" may have done even greater harm.

Also note that this is a SSD, so it may have included TRIMming the blocks.

I would boot a Live Disk and attempt to mount the partition. Linux won't care much about how the partition is described, so if the contents are there, you can probably view everything with it.

After you confirm that data is indeed there, you can then work on getting Windows recognise it.

Comment: It won't let me right click it actually, so I'll boot into Gentoo and try what you suggested.